# How to run makemigrations for dockerized django app

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I have been trying to setup a django app using this guide:

https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/

And it was a great resource to get everything up and running. However i have problem now when it comes to migrations. Say i add a model, add data into my db, and later i change the model. Now i can run makemigrations using the exec method on the container, but when i shut down my migrations are not stored in my local files i save to my git project, instead they are lost as i spin down the container.

Does anyone know how to solve this, how do you makemigrations is such a setup where you run two dockerized django/postgres dev/prod environments?

Comment: You should run makemigrations locally, then only run `migrate` on the docker server itself

Comment: But can you run makemigrations locally when you are not connected to the db? In the example of from the guide, the db is part of the services in the docker-compose file